# FQL and place locations?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Something I've been playing with is getting address information from FQL queries. For example, I can get a place, but it doesn't have any of the location information beyond the lat/lng.

Is there a way that I can get a place and have it include the location address?

Looking at this page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/place - I'm not sure how this could be done, and scanning the documentation, I can't seem to find the ability to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this if it is not saved for that place 
write 
https://graph.facebook.com/[page id of location/place]
Like this 
https://graph.facebook.com/the.logic.unit
then see all details of location are here or not.
If there is no detail here then you are cannot get details.

Comment: I don't believe the graph search is the "complete" search. Everything I've seen and been able to do myself, the graph search is the simplified search, but not always the most complete or the fastest. I've been able to query post data at twice the speed as a graph search by using FQL. The link above to the FQL appears to be the most thorough list of what's available for every "object type" in facebook.

Comment: explain your scenario what you want to achieve??? is it a street number, zip code etc ?

Comment: 178651355673569?fields=location
Write this in graph api, use id of your own.